# In Reactjs browser what are rendering Real DOM or Virtual DOM?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I understand before rendering a application reactjs creating a Copy of Real DOM as Virtual DOM and store it local memory.

Please tell me what is rendering in react js

Comment: This is really a deep topic. https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-internals.html should answer your basic question. React doesn't actually "create a copy" of a real dom.

Answer (score 0):

I think, Rendering in React is done by creating a Virtual DOM which is the copy or the blueprint of the Real DOM in simple terms, and everytime we made changes in the code all changes happen in the Virtual DOM instead of real DOM and then react compare REAL and VIRTUAL DOM, and when it finds some node in REAL DOM which is not matching the  VIRTUAL DOM it replace that node and it's children with the updated node instead of recreating the whole tree.

ALL of this is know as Reconciliation I think which uses diffing algorithm and from react v16 or v15 not sure, this Reconciliation has 2 Phases, commit and render phase which are synchronous and asynchronous respectively, means all states changes, all the side effects are done in the render phase and painting of the DOM is done in the commit phase which can't be intercepted.

So this is what I think how react do the rendering process in simple terms.

You can get more information about react in [these videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7YhdqIR2Yzo&list=PLxRVWC-K96b0ktvhd16l3xA6gncuGP7gJ)

---

Please do correct me if anyone thinks I am wrong or if I missed anything important about the rendering process.

Answer (score 0):

We often use the word "render" interchangeably, but rendering in a general sense refers to the process which is done by browser on the screen. Here, Rendering means, it is displaying something on the screen.

Where as in React: React keeps an in-memory representation of UI elements, so this manipulation is cheap as just we are restructuring the tree object(representation of UI) present in the memory, not the actual DOM, so whenever a state of the component is changed, react observes this and creates a new virtual DOM which is again in the memory (which matches with the present state),now it applies reconciliation algorithm which compares two virtual DOMS (in-memory objects) and identifies what changes it has to make in order to minimize the actual DOM so that the actual DOM will match to the present state(i.e, new VDOM) and applies this to Actual DOM. This process of updating the Actual DOM after diffing by react is called rendering. So when you read or hear that Component is rendered, or when you hear something like "react renders this/that", we mean that that object is updated in the actual DOM by react.

Now after react renders( that means, after react updates the actual DOM , browser will do necessary repaints/reflows and renders on the screen.).

Answer (score 0):

In React.js, the rendering process primarily involves working with the Virtual DOM (Document Object Model), not the Real DOM. React introduces the concept of a Virtual DOM, which is an abstraction of the Real DOM. It's a lightweight, in-memory representation of the actual DOM elements. React components render to the Virtual DOM first, rather than directly to the browser's Real DOM. When you make changes to your React components, React creates a new Virtual DOM tree representing the updated state of your application.
React then compares this new Virtual DOM tree with the previous one using a process called **"diffing"** or **"reconciliation"** . **Diffing** is the process of comparing the new Virtual DOM tree with the previous one to identify the differences or changes made. Once React identifies the differences between the new and old Virtual DOM trees, it updates the Real DOM with only the necessary changes.
This process is known as **reconciliation**. The **Fiber reconciler** is an updated algorithm that plays a crucial role in the rendering process by making it more efficient and responsive. It builds upon the concepts of the Virtual DOM, diffing, and reconciliation.
I hope my answer helps you understand the rendering in React.